# How do I map dates with a specific ID in textfield value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks, tsx

I have an array with objects called `dates`, example of one object in the array: `{id: 9898, date: 10/06/2020}`.

In the array, there will be many objects with same id, I want to map dates with same id in `TextField`, see code below. How do I achieve that?

- Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextField, Box, Button, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';

   return(
           <div>
                {dates.map(dateValue => (
                    <div>
                        <TextField label="Date" value={dateValue.date} fullWidth />
                        <Box mt="1.5rem" />
                    </div>
                ))}
                    <div>
                        <TextField
                            name="date"
                            id="date"
                            label="New date"
                            inputRef={register}
                            fullWidth />
                    </div>
                <Box mt="1.5rem" />
            </div>
         );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to use  **uuid**, like [react-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid)

> A UUID (Universal Unique Identifier) is a 128-bit number used to uniquely identify some object or entity on the Internet.

```
import uuid from "react-uuid";

const udates = dates.map(x => ({ ...x, uuid: uuid() }));

<div key={dateValue.uuid} ... />
```

---

You can also use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

```
import {v5 as uuid} from "uuid";
```

They have the typescript support [@types/uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/uuid)

Comment: The objects already have an id. My problem is that I want to show all the dates, which has the same id. :)

Comment: Library `react-uuid` can't be used with typescript. Is there any other version for typescript?

Comment: @lo7 You can also use `uuid` refer to the updated content